# Tkinter flickering when update gui with many widgets

Tags: tkinter

Is it possible to update frame (remove existing widgets and create new) without flickering? This example is simplified. In the reality the form can contain different widgets in different order so update existing widgets is not the solution. But if you press A,B,A,A... I still see some disturbing flickering. I would like to see something like instant switching between two images.
Reason why I ask is, that I have much more complicated app which shows something like dynamic form (dozens of rows with options where each option can cause change in form under this option, hide or add options etc.) I have noticed strange behaviour: when I change any option which does not affect other option and the form is refreshed (remove widgets and create same content) I see flickering. But when I change an option which affects the form (add another option), there is no flickering although the process is still the same (destroy all widgets and create new ones)

**EDIT: added link to [youtube](https://youtu.be/YN-VgcGmqSY) video**

```py
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('400x900')
        self.resizable(width=0, height=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1, uniform='a')
        tk.Button(text='A', command=lambda: self.add(20)).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Button(text='B', command=lambda: self.add(30)).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Button(text='clear', command=lambda: self.add(0)).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nsew')
        self.form = tk.Frame()
        self.form.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.form.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.form.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')
        self.mainloop()

    def add(self, n):
        # self.form.grid_remove()
        # self.update()
        for child in self.form.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()

        for i in range(0, 2 * n, 2):
            name = f'Row {i // 2 + 1}'
            tk.Label(master=self.form, text=name, bg='sky blue').grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='nsew')
            tk.Button(master=self.form, text=name, relief='flat', bg='white').grid(row=i, column=1, sticky='nsew')
            tk.Frame(master=self.form, height=1, bg='black').grid(row=i + 1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
        # self.form.grid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
```

Comment: I don't see any flickering when I click A and B repeatedly.

Comment: What you see is that you destroy and create new widgets. You should configure them instead.

Comment: Hi Bryan, thank you for reply. A have added video where the described behaviour is visible. I work on PC Windows 11

Comment: If you want to notify someone about your message, you can do that by @BryanOakley

Comment: Ok, thanks. Hi @BryanOakley, thank you for reply. A have added video where the described behaviour is visible. I work on PC Windows 11, Python 3.8. On the right window is other app also written in python(tkinter). You can see that if Ichange an option (Local controller) which adds row. There is no flicering/blinking. But when I change row "Visualization" the flickering is visible. What is done behind the form is always the same job: show JSON as form, sande request to another packege, obtain a new JSON and show form. All widgets are destroyed during this job

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which works great but I think there should be a better way how to achieve this (with one Frame). In this example I alternate two frames. One is "in background" and the second one "in foreground". When adding widgets, I always use the one in background and then I call tkrise method to move it to foreground. update_idletasks() is also important. As you can see in video, this looks 100% better than the previous example. This is important when let say you want to show attributes of one object and then switch to another one and show its attributes. When there is only one different value for both objects, you can easily identify with eye which one has changed during switch. But when whole frame is flashing during switch is almost impossible to spot the change.

**link to [youtube](https://youtu.be/cWQP6y5ZRXo) video**

```py
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('400x900')
        self.resizable(width=0, height=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1, uniform='a')
        tk.Button(text='A', command=lambda: self.add(20)).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Button(text='B', command=lambda: self.add(30)).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Button(text='clear', command=lambda: self.add(0)).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nsew')

        self.forms = (tk.Frame(self), tk.Frame(self))
        for form in self.forms:
            form.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            form.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
            form.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')
        self.form = self.forms[1]
        self.mainloop()

    def switch_form(self):
        for form in self.forms:
            if form is not self.form:
                self.form = form
                break

    def add(self, n):
        for child in self.form.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
        self.switch_form()
        for i in range(0, 2 * n, 2):
            name = f'Row {i // 2 + 1}'
            tk.Label(master=self.form, text=name, bg='sky blue').grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='nsew')
            tk.Button(master=self.form, text=name, relief='flat', bg='white').grid(row=i, column=1, sticky='nsew')
            tk.Frame(master=self.form, height=1, bg='black').grid(row=i + 1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')

        self.update_idletasks()
        self.form.tkraise()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
```